# how to make my segmented control in swift delegate

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

so i have a segmented control in my project 
the things i want is if i click no on my segmented control
-it will check validation and if all validation already done the button will change colour and my button is enable

if i click yes on my button
-it will show another textfield and my button will deactivate until all validation already done

but my problem is if i click no when all validation already done and i click yes again my next button still active except if i click a textfield and click the done button.

here is my code

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        if(alamatIdentitasTextField.text != ""  && provinsiIdentitasTextField.text != "" && kotaIdentitasTextField.text != "" &&   kelurahanIdentitasTextField.text != "" && kecamatanIdentitasTextField.text != "" && kodePosIdentitasTextField.text != "" ){


            if alamatDomisiliSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {

                if(alamatDomisiliTextField.text != ""  && provinsiDomisiliTextField.text != "" && kotaDomisiliTextField.text != "" &&   kelurahanDomisiliTextField.text != "" && kecamatanDomisiliLabel.text != "" && kodePosDomisiliTextField.text != "" ){
                    nextButton.isEnabled = true
                    nextButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.4431372549, blue: 0.003921568627, alpha: 1)
                }else {

                    nextButton.isEnabled = false
                    nextButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.662745098, green: 0.662745098, blue: 0.662745098, alpha: 1)
                }

            }else if alamatDomisiliSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {

                nextButton.isEnabled = true
                nextButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.4431372549, blue: 0.003921568627, alpha: 1)

            }else {

                nextButton.isEnabled = false
                nextButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.662745098, green: 0.662745098, blue: 0.662745098, alpha: 1)
            }
        }else {

            nextButton.isEnabled = false
            nextButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.662745098, green: 0.662745098, blue: 0.662745098, alpha: 1)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you disable the nextButton and validate incase the segementedControl's value changes?

Comment: sorry for late reply,yess the button will disable and validate when sgmented control changes

Comment: `i click yes again my next button still active`: This sounds like there is no validation done when the segmented control changes. Can you show the code that executes when the segmented control changes? The validation code you show here is in the `textFieldDidEndEditing` after all which does not sound like its gonna be executed on segmented-control-change.